# Pandas GroupBy Two columns, where the second is the average containing both numeric and string data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by

Morning All,

```
df = {
'inc_priority2':['Critical','Critical','Critical','High','High','High','Medium','Medium','Low'],
'inc_open_minutes':['No Data',10,6,
                    'No Data',4,2,
                    'No Data',5,
                    3],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(df))
print(df)

 inc_priority2 inc_open_minutes
0      Critical          No Data
1      Critical               10
2      Critical                6
3          High          No Data
4          High                4
5          High                2
6        Medium          No Data
7        Medium                5
8           Low                3
```

Desired output i.e conditional average of all open incidents but only where there is data:

```
  inc_priority2  Avg inc_open_minutes
0      Critical                 8
1          High                 3
2        Medium                 5
3           Low                 3
```

The following works if the `No Data` values are converted to 0 but as it stands I get an error as trying to average strings:

```
dfTemp = df.groupby('inc_priority2').inc_open_minutes.apply(np.mean).reset_index()
display(dfTemp)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

If I did replace `No Data` with `0`, the question is similar i.e. conditional and how to average non-zero values only in the groupby

Comment: Filter the dataframe first then groupby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
pd.to_numeric(df['inc_open_minutes'], errors='coerce').groupby(df['inc_priority2']).mean()
```

Output:

```
inc_priority2
Critical    8.0
High        3.0
Low         3.0
Medium      5.0
Name: inc_open_minutes, dtype: float64
```

Or,

```
mask = pd.to_numeric(df['inc_open_minutes'], errors='coerce').notna()
df[mask].groupby('inc_priority2').mean()
```

Output:

```
               inc_open_minutes
inc_priority2                  
Critical                    8.0
High                        3.0
Low                         3.0
Medium                      5.0
```